# Complex Search query in Elastic Search 5

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I have following record in my elastic search database.

```
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-30",
    "tim": "2017-01-19T11:02:21.847",
    "tpr": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-29",
    "tim": "2017-01-19T11:02:21.847",
    "tpr": 2408.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-28",
    "tim": "2017-01-20T12:01:08.358",
    "tpr": 2408.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-30",
    "tim": "2017-01-20T12:01:08.358",
    "tpr": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-30",
    "tim": "2017-01-20T17:35:17.495",
    "tpr": 2408.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-30",
    "tim": "2017-01-19T10:04:44.586",
    "tpr": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "frd": "2017-06-30",
    "tim": "2017-01-19T10:15:46.051",
    "tpr": 2276.5
  }
```

Elastic version is 5. I am going to create a multi series line chart from above data set so I want to get a new `json` from above data as below.

```
[
  {
    "tim": "2017-01-19T11:02:21.847",
    "2017-06-28": null,
    "2017-06-29": 2408.5,
    "2017-06-30": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "tim": "2017-01-20T12:01:08.358",
    "2017-06-28": 2408.5,
    "2017-06-29": null,
    "2017-06-30": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "tim": "2017-01-20T17:35:17.495",
    "2017-06-28": null,
    "2017-06-29": null,
    "2017-06-30": 2408.5
  },
  {
    "tim": "2017-01-19T10:04:44.586",
    "2017-06-28": null,
    "2017-06-29": null,
    "2017-06-30": 2276.5
  },
  {
    "tim": "2017-01-19T10:15:46.051",
    "2017-06-28": null,
    "2017-06-29": null,
    "2017-06-30": 2276.5
  }
]
```

X axis becomes **tim** values. Y axis becomes **tpr**. Lines should be group by **frd**.

Is there a way to get above chart data set from elastic data with elastic search query?

Thank you

Comment: not sure if you can, but wouldn't the parser for this be easier to write/maintain rather than the complex query?

Comment: Can I do this with elastic search aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

For visualising you can directly use Kibana (v5). There in you can make the line chart directly by selecting whatever fields you want to

Here is the link to [User guide of Kibana 5.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index.html)